# Required Sum result in separate columns as per different elements in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new in SQL basically i required Sum result in separate columns as per different elements.

Please find my table and required result in below image.

[image]

Please guide me with regards to SQL query which give me the required result.

Comment: Depends on whether the set of Products is fixed or varying. If its varying, that'll require dynamic SQL, and that in turn will mean you really do need to decide if you're using [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server], which are two separate products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` to get the desired result

```
SELECT  * ,
    [A] + [B] + [C] + [D] AS Total
FROM    ( SELECT    Payment, Product, Amount FROM  Your_Table) tr 
PIVOT( SUM(Amount) FOR Product IN ( [A], [B], [C], [D] ) ) p;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select payment,
       sum(case when product = 'A' then amount else 0 end) as a,
       sum(case when product = 'B' then amount else 0 end) as b,
       sum(case when product = 'C' then amount else 0 end) as c,
       sum(case when product = 'D' then amount else 0 end) as d,
       sum(amount) as total
from t
group by payment;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic SQL pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) if your products are not limited with A,B,C and D
Here is a sample query for SQL Server

```
DECLARE @products nvarchar(max)
SELECT @products =
 STUFF(
 (
  select distinct ',[' + product + ']'
  from Payments
  for xml path('')
 ),
 1,1,'')

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = '
SELECT
 *
FROM (
 SELECT
  Payment AS '' '',
  Product,
  Amount
 from Payments
) Data
PIVOT (
 SUM(Amount)
 FOR Product
 IN (
' + @products + ' 
 )
) PivotTable'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')IS NOT NULL
DROp TABLE #t
;with cte (Payment,Product,Amount)
AS
(
SELECT 'Cash','A',1         UNION ALL
SELECT 'Credit','B',2       UNION ALL
SELECT 'Credit','C',3       UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cash','D',5         UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cash','A',6         UNION ALL
SELECT 'Credit','B',23      UNION ALL
SELECT 'Credit','C',7       UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cash','D',11        UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cash','A',12        UNION ALL
SELECT 'Credit','B',14      UNION ALL
SELECT 'Credit','C',16      UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cash','D',26            
)
SELECT * INTO #t FROM cte
```

Using Dynamic Sql

```
DECLARE @DyColumn Nvarchar(max),
        @Sql Nvarchar(max),
        @ISNULLDyColumn Nvarchar(max),
        @SumCol Nvarchar(max)


SELECT @DyColumn=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(Product) FROM #t FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @ISNULLDyColumn=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+'ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(Product)+',''0'')' +' AS '+QUOTENAME(Product) FROM #t FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
SELECT @SumCol=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ' + '+QUOTENAME(Product) FROM #t FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')



SET @Sql='
SELECT *,('+@SumCol+') AS Total FROM
    (
    SELECT Payment,'+@ISNULLDyColumn+'
    FROM
    (
    SELECT * FROM #t
    )AS
    SRC
     PIVOT
    (
    SUM(AMOUNT) FOR Product IN ('+@DyColumn+')
     ) AS Pvt
    )dt
 '
 PRINT @Sql
 EXECUTE (@Sql)
```

Result

```
 Payment    A   B   C   D   Total
 ---------------------------------
 Cash      19   0   0   42  61
 Credit    0    39  26  0   65
```